# Flask + Peewee: where to create tables?

Tags: python, flask, peewee

Instead of **flask-peewee** I'm using plain **peewee** package.

Here's the way I'm initializing the database:

```
import os

# just extending the BaseFlask with yaml config reader
from . extensions.flask_app import Flask

# peewee's wrapper around the database
from playhouse.flask_utils import FlaskDB


db_wrapper = FlaskDB() 


# define the application factory
def create_app(env):

    app = Flask(__name__)

    # load config depending on the environment
    app.config.from_yaml(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'config.yml'), env)

    # init extensions
    db_wrapper.init_app(app)

    # ...
```

I know that I should call this to create tables:

```
from . models import User

db_wrapper.database.connect()
db_wrapper.database.create_tables([User])
```

But where do I put the **table creation code**, so that the database would be already **initialized**?

**Edit**

Looking at the [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/projects/flask-peewee/en/latest/getting-started.html#adding-users-to-the-site) I found out that I can use `User.create_table(fail_silently=True)` like that:

```
# in app/__init__.py

# define the application factory
def create_app(env):

    app = Flask(__name__)

    # load config depending on the environment
    app.config.from_yaml(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'config.yml'), env)

    # init extensions
    db_wrapper.init_app(app)

    create_tables();

    # rest of the initialization

def create_tables():

    from . models import User    
    User.create_table(fail_silently=True)
```

Is it alright to do it here? Or is there a better way/tool for this?

**Edit**

Figured it out. Please, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I didn't know about the built-in **CLI** support in **Flask**. I don't know whether you should consider such an approach at all, since you can do things out of the box (see [documntation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/cli/)).

---

I can utilize the **flask-script** package. I've done it before, just overlooked it.

Activate your **virtual environment** and **run**:

> **pip** install flask-script

Then create **manage.py** file in your root directory, add these lines:

```
import os
from app import create_app, db_wrapper
from app.models import *
from flask_script import Manager, Shell

# create the application instance    
app = create_app(os.getenv('FLASK_ENV', 'development'))

# instantiate script manager
manager = Manager(app)

def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db_wrapper=db_wrapper, User=User)


@manager.command
def run_shell():
    Shell(make_context = make_shell_context).run(no_ipython=True, no_bpython=True)


# here's my simple command
@manager.command
def create_tables():
    User.create_table(fail_silently=True)


@manager.command
def run_tests():
    import unittest
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)


# run it
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Comment: Be sure to clean up your connections after creating the tables!

Comment: @coleifer Do you mean I need to call `db.close()`, `db.open()`?

Comment: db.close() -- there's no db.open() though there is a db.connect() . It's not necessary to call connect() as it will be called the first time you attempt to execute a query on a closed database. Of course I think it's good to be explicit and call connect(), but not necessary strictly.

Comment: @coleifer ok, got it. Thank you.

Comment: @lexeme this is not creating any tables in my DB. Any suggestions!

Comment: @NaveenPandia do you have any output? Error text? Create a question here or drop git gist (strip sensitive information).

Comment: @lexeme how should i run this .. I'm using "python manage.py run" or should I run it with command I've created "python manage.py create_tables run".

Comment: @NaveenPandia try running `python manage.py create_tables`

Comment: @lexeme Is there any way to run create_tables and run at the same time because if using both functions it is giving 
```
"usage: manage.py [-?] {run_shell,create_tables,run,shell,runserver} ...
manage.py: error: too many arguments".
```
and if I add migrations will this create_tables implement migrations too.. I am trying to add migrations in models using migrate() command.

Comment: @Naveen Pandia 1. You can use `&&` → `python manage.py create_tables && python manage.py run_shell`. You can create Makefile to alias your commands to shorter names. 2. `create_tables` command will execute only those commands you define inside the function body. `create_tables` is just a convinient name, this could be any other name.

Comment: @lexeme Thank you so much for your help.

Will this be a viable option if I had to run migrations too?

Comment: @NaveenPandia I don't really remember why I needed it myself) And I've totally forgotten how to deal with migrations in Flask's eco-system. Some systems consider creating db schema and seeding the db separate activities (migrations and seeds). In my current project I mostly stick to migrations (schema migrations + seed/data migrations). It just depends. Commands let you execute repetitive tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252063/discussion-between-naveen-pandia-and-lexeme).